# Close Activity once score has been shown

Tags: java, android

I have a quiz that finishes with a score screen once the "Show score" button has been clicked. However I want to know how to then automatically close the quiz and return back to my main activity after score has been shown for a few seconds.

```
public void showScore(View view) {
    // Calculate the number of correct answers after the "Show score" button is tapped.
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Do your other functions //
            int score = calculateScore(answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4);
            // Convert the correct answer-to-question ratio to percentage.
            float percentage = score * 100 / 4;
            // Show the percentage score in a toast

            Toast.makeText(this, "Your score: " + percentage + "%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(EmotionsActivity.this, ActivitiesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish(); // closes after score has been shown
                }
            }, 2000); // Set your time here //
        }
    });
```

Error:

```
error: no suitable method found for makeText(<anonymous 
OnClickListener>,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to 
Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `postDelayed` on Button Click and change activities using intent. Example:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do your other functions //
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityQuiz.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
                    }
                }, 5000); // Set your time here //
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why use an Intent when only `finish()` will do the job that is removing the current quiz activity from the stack and bringing up the previous main activity?? or am I missing something which I think I'm not?

Comment: I've made the changes however getting an error with the toast. Error above in code

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar When I use just finish() it will close immediately instead i need it to delay closing until the score has been shown for a few seconds

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar The OP didn't mention that the last activity is the Main Activity. AFAIK `finish()` is fine for two activities, not multiple. I mentioned `intent` as a generalized answer.

Comment: @DavidG Instead of using `Toast.makeText(this, "Your score: "....`, use `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Score: .....`.

Comment: @Davidg it's not about immediately closing as for that you're bound to use handler or other time-based schedulers but it's about the finish().

Comment: @Abhi your answer does imply for all the queris related to this but for specifically this, the solution should be as short as possible that is why commented. You and I, we both know that your answer will function same as using finish() for two activities so it's was just curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

use the method postDelayed of https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler class to call finish() on activity.

Comment: If using postDelayed, make sure to properly handle the Activity life cycle. Do not forget to take into consideration that the user might rotate the device or put your app to the background before the handler executed the call to finish.